# Variable not seen as defined in foreach of a hash

Tags: perl, foreach

```
my $crazy_hash = {

  'One' => 1,

  'Two' => 1,

  'Three' => 1,

};


 foreach my $num (keys %crazy_hash) {
      #DoSomething    
  }
```

The error I get is:

Global symbol "%crazy_hash" requires explicit package name at blah line blah

If I do my %crazy_hash and define it within the loop, it works. Why doesn't it work as is?

Comment: try `foreach my $num (keys %$crazy_hash)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$crazy_hash` is a reference to an anonymous hash. Prior to 5.14, you need to dereference the reference for [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) to work:

```
for my $num (keys %{$crazy_hash}) {
```

Starting with 5.14:

> Starting with Perl 5.14, keys can take a scalar EXPR, which must contain a reference to an unblessed hash or array. The argument will be dereferenced automatically. This aspect of keys is considered highly experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl.

Answer (score 4):

You have not defined a hash called `%crazy_hash`, you have defined a scalar `$crazy_hash` which contains a reference to a hash.

You probably mean this:

```
my %crazy_hash = ( One => 1, ...
```

... or access the keys with `keys %{$crazy_hash}` like others have suggested; then you will need to use `$crazy_hash->{key}` rather than `$crazy_hash{key}` to access a value. Read perlreftut if you need to understand references.